# Convert date 'yyyymmdd hh24:MI:SS' to yyyy-mm-ddTHH24:MI:SS

Tags: postgresql

Convert date format:

Ex: convert

```
'20160203 16:00:00' to '2016-02-03T16:00:00'
'20160204 15:59:59' to '2016-02-04T15:59:59'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp('20160204 15:59:59','yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS'),
               'yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS')
-- 2016-02-04T15:59:59
```

or:

```
SELECT to_char('20160204 15:59:59'::timestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS')
-- 2016-02-04T15:59:59
```